# Can a form load another form onsubmit without having to redirecting or reloading the page?

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

Assume that you want to display two separate forms on one page, but only one at a time.

One form acts as a gate for the other form, and would disappear upon submission, being replaced by the second form.

Is it possible to display a second form on POST on the same page without having to reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

Not without using Javascript in some method or other.  Best bet would be to post the first form via AJAX and in the response delivery the second form.

Comment: i am new to this so could you point me in the direction of some helpful tutorials? thank you!

Comment: If you're new what I'd suggest is just doing it via pure HTML and using two pages with forms in.  If you're really set on it, then I'd suggest using jQuery for doing the AJAX bit - there are dozens of things online depending upon your level of knowledge. Check out: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ and look at the example "Post a form using ajax and put results in a div".  However this might be double dutch to you...